# Symfony2 - Drop down with the possibility of adding fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jquery-select2, symfony-forms

Sorry for my english.
I need to create a drop down list (select option) with values ​​taken from an Entity.
I must also add options (I use select2 to do this).
When I send the form it doesn't work. How can I configure the field type to make it work?
I need the possibilities to adding multiple persons

My current code is

```
...
->add('person', 'entity', array(
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'tags'
    ),
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Person',
    'data_class' => null,
    'label' => 'Persons',
    'mapped' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => false
));
```

Select2

```
$('select.tags').select2({
    language: 'it',
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    width: '100%'
});
```

Error message

```
The offset "0" does not exist.
```